# React component communication with Native Mobile (iOS or Android)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, web-applications, reactjs

I understand that this might not be the best design approach. I am forced to conform to an existing architecture.

Given the following set of React components. How would one accomplish the following senerio.

ReactComponentInstance <-Communication-> Native iOS or Android

Overview:

1. A General React component which is responsible for managing an image.
2. Upon click of this image the React component makes a call out to the Native Application to invoke a view with the data. (I have means of managing this part already).
3. Native code performs some processing on the data.(This logic does not matter.).
4. The Challenge I am encountering. How to call back to the same instance of the React component which invoked the native code.

The communication between the Webapp and Native app is handled via javascript bridge.

```
var ImageClass = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function (){
    return {
      imgURL:"http://i0.wp.com/www.compusurf.es/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/smiley.jpeg?fit=1200%2C1200"
    }
  },
  didCompleteMobileProcessing: function (data){
    //This function should only be invoked on the specific instance which invoked the native code. 
    //Invoked when the Mobile native code is done processing image.
    //Populate image with new data form native app. 
    //this.setState(data);  
  },
  handleClick: function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Image Clicked");
    //Load mobile Native View. Sending it the image and allow it to process data
    //LoadNativeView(this.state.imgURL);
  },
  render: function (){
    return(
      <span className="ImageContainer">
        <img onClick={this.handleClick} src={this.state.imgURL} alt="ImageBox" align="center"/>
      </span> 
    ); 
  }
});


var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <ImageClass/> //Instance 1
        <ImageClass/> //Instance 2
        <ImageClass/> //Instance 3
        <ImageClass/> //Instance 4
        <ImageClass/> //Instance 5
      </div>
    );      
  }
});
```

Comment: Why not just wire up an event in these components to listen to changes from the native code? The bridge could signal back which would then transfer to any component interested in that message.

Comment: From my understanding the event would then be fired on all instances of the ImageClass component not allowing for distinction between them. Or am I over thinking this?

Comment: You'll need to have a unique key or something to make the connection between the native and JavaScript code. You don't have one necessarily right now, but you could just use a generated unique number for each. Pass the key to the native code so that when it returns, it responds with that key. Using the key, you could raise an event that would be handled by the component listening for that specific key. `LoadNativeView(this.myKey, this.state.imgUrl)`

Comment: WiredPrairie could I kindly ask you to provide a small example of how this could be accomplished inside React. While maintaing reference to the react component.

Answer (score 1):

You can communicate between native and react native using commands.

Using these two methods in ViewGroupManager

```
getCommandsMap()
receiveCommand()
```

Here is a detailed [explaination](https://medium.com/@john1jan/communicating-to-and-from-native-ui-components-in-react-native-android-b8abcfb2f9c8#.8tnjasy3g)